# How to extract values from HTML <input type="date"> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

Using an HTML `input type="date"` and a submit button. I would like to populate the variables `day`, `month`, and `year` with the appropriate values from the date input.

```
<input type="date" id="date-input" required />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

and the jQuery:

```
var day, month, year;

$('#submit').on('click', function(){
  day = $('#date-input').getDate();
  month = $('#date-input').getMonth() + 1;
  year = $('#date-input').getFullYear();
  alert(day, month, year);
});
```

Here's a code sample:
https://jsfiddle.net/dkxy46ha/

the console error is telling me that `.getDate()` is not a function.

I have seen similar questions but the solutions have not worked for me. How can I extract the day, month and year from the `input type="date"`? Thanks

Comment: value is string you need to create `new Date` from

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Firstly you need to create a `Date` object from `input` element value. And then you will be able to get day, month and year from this object.

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
  var date = new Date($('#date-input').val());
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  alert([day, month, year].join('/'));
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8poLtqvp/

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work. The day if off by +/- 1. If you add 1 to it, you risk invalid dates.

Comment: Use getUTCDate() as opposed to getDate(). The same goes for month and year.

Answer (score 9):

Date value returned by `input type="date"` is format `yyyy-mm-dd` . Could use `.split()` with argument `"-"` to retrieve array containing `[yyyy, mm, dd]`

Note, `alert()` expects string as parameter ; does not print values same as `console.log()` with comma `,` operator

```
var day, month, year;

$('#submit').on('click', function() {
  var date = $('#date-input').val().split("-");
    console.log(date, $('#date-input').val())
  day = date[2];
  month = date[1];
  year = date[0];
  alert(day + month + year);
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dkxy46ha/2/

Answer (score 5):

```
date = new Date($('#date-input').val())
date.getDate()
```

...

Comment: It will not work. You need to get value of input. And only then create `Date` object

Comment: date = new Date($('#date-input').val())

Answer (score 1):

```
        <input type="date" id="date-input"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>


<script>
      $('#submit').on('click', function(){
              var date = new Date($('#date-input').val());
              var day = $('#date-input').getDate();
              var month = $('#date-input').getMonth() + 1;
              var year = $('#date-input').getFullYear();
              alert(day+"/"+ month+"/"+year);
            });
    </script>
```

**Date class will convert input data into date type. Then getMonth() gives us value from 0-11 so we can either consider January
as 0 or we can add 1 to received value that's what I did here.**

Here I just used Jquery to fetch date, months and year respectively and if you want to post the data you can convert that values into string.

Comment: you should alway explain what your code does. It will be more helpful for everybody also in the future

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you can provide details on how you arrive on this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Advantage of JQuery ? A few lines of code do a lot !!

`alert` only takes a string as its parameter.
So simply, we just have to pass our Date object as a string using th `String` built-in-Function.

Just replace the button tag with this...

```
<button onclick="alert(String( $("#date-input").val() ))">Submit</button>
```

You can do further manipulations on the string you'll be alerted as `yyyy-mm-dd`