# Date input in javascript, detect if year, month or day was selected

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

Is it possible to detect event on different parts of an input date field.

```
<input type="date" value="2018-08-15">
```

In other words did the user select the year, the month or the day(in this specific scenario).

Comment: Do you mean detecting when the user *changes* the day, month or year by *select*? If so, would a Javascript function getting the full date and  check which fields of the data changed be plausible to you?

Comment: I don't think so there is a specific event or function for that, you have to write your own js for this.
on change, check whats change compare to oldvalue

Comment: The presentation of controls for input type date is implementation dependent, so you can't be sure that there is any of those that can be "selected".

Comment: remember, input type `date` - is not supported in Safari or IE, and only partially supported by Firefox - https://caniuse.com/#search=date

Comment: No not when the user changes the value, i mean when the value gets selected. Maybe i should clarify what im trying to do. Im implementing a datepicker, using a pure css framework as a base(bulma). And i wanted to add the additional feature. If you select the year i want the datepicker to open in the "Year view".
Thus detecting changes will not help unfortunatly.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597361/parse-date-month-and-year-from-javascript-date-form or jQuery version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312318/how-to-extract-values-from-html-input-type-date-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You could use .split. 
Start at 0, then use a regex to separate user input at slashes.
Now you can check each array index for a value other than the default.

Something like this. (untested)

```
var d = document.getElementById('date').value;
var dArray = d.split(0, /\//);
for (var i = 0; i < i.length; i++;) {
    if ((dArray[i] === 'mm') || (dArray[i] === 'dd') || (dArray[i] === 'yyyy') { 
        // date incomplete
    }
}
```

Note: the date element doesn't have full browser support yet.

Comment: This should be a comment, it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the date element refuses to give incomplete data (`value` returns nothing if the date is incomplete), but when it is complete we can simply check for changes from the last time it was changed, ignoring the empty arrays.

Do notice that the `change` event only fires on valid input changes (or from valid input to invalid input), so if a part of the date input (date/month/year) is invalid, the others won't trigger change until the invalid part is turned valid (which does trigger change).

```js
function dateListener(e) {
  let arr = e.target.value.split('-');
  if(!this.prevArr)this.prevArr=[];
  if(this.prevArr[0] != arr[0] && arr[0]) {
    console.log(`The year was changed from ${this.prevArr[0]} to ${arr[0]}`);
  }
  if(this.prevArr[1] != arr[1] && arr[1]) {
    console.log(`The month was changed from ${this.prevArr[1]} to ${arr[1]}`);
  }
  if(this.prevArr[2] != arr[2] && arr[2]) {
    console.log(`The date was changed from ${this.prevArr[2]} to ${arr[2]}`);
  }
  if(arr[0]) this.prevArr=arr; //If the date is falsey (undefined/empty string), so is the whole array.
};

document.getElementById("datefield").addEventListener("change", dateListener);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datefield" />
```

What we're doing here is taking advantage of the fact that functions are objects, and settings a variable on the function to save the previous state of the input. Of course we don't have to do that and we could create a variable that's not bound to the function to save that date, but I chose to do this because of comfortability.

Comment: This throws an error in Firefox. In Safari it reports that the year has changed when any part of the date changes. Adding custom properties to DOM nodes isn't a good idea. When called as a listener, `e.srcElement === this`, it would be better to use one or the other, not both.

Comment: @RobG it appears you're right, stupid mistake on my end :P Fixed

Comment: "Unfortunately the date element refuses to give incomplete data" - This can be fixed by pre-populating the date value.